# JavaScript instead of repetitive HTML lines

Tags: javascript, html

in my html files I have something like this:

```
<p class="image">
<img src="images/20.jpg" alt="20!" width="90" height="125" border="0">
<img src="images/19.jpg" alt="19!" width="90" height="125" border="0">
<img src="images/18.jpg" alt="18!" width="90" height="125" border="0">
<img src="images/17.jpg" alt="17!" width="90" height="125" border="0">
<img src="images/16.jpg" alt="16!" width="90" height="125" border="0">
<img src="images/15.jpg" alt="15!" width="90" height="125" border="0">
<img src="images/14.jpg" alt="14!" width="90" height="125" border="0">
<img src="images/13.jpg" alt="13!" width="90" height="125" border="0">
<img src="images/12.jpg" alt="12!" width="90" height="125" border="0">
<img src="images/11.jpg" alt="11!" width="90" height="125" border="0">
</p>
```

Is there possibility to replace repetetive codes with any loop script? I am totally new in this :)

Comment: Where is the data coming from? is there any database then this should be solved by a backed programing language i.e PHP, ASP.

Comment: What code? Html is a markup language. There is no code in html?

Comment: Can this use jquery?

Comment: @jadwiga  it is appropriate now for you to select an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript: - Using the for loop to count down and adding the HTML within the demo id.

```js
text = "";
var c;

for (var c=20;c > 10;c--){
    text += '<img src="images/' + c + '.jpg" alt="' + c + '!" width="90" height="125" border="0">';
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow has their own jsfiddle kind of thing nowadays, http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Oh you beat me to it but about 2 seconds :)  I up-voted you... Guess great minds think alike :)

Comment: @w3bMak3r LOL! another way for us not to leave the site! And i think its Azeirah who is being a min-mod, down-voting people (including myself), annoying as hell!

Answer (score 1):

To not use jQuery and only use JavaScript I would do something like follows:

(To make things easier I gave the p tag an id rather then a class.  We can use a class to it just requires another line of code.)

HTML

```
<p id="image">

</p>
```

Javascript:

```
for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
    document.getElementById('image').innerHTML += '<img src="http://placehold.it/350x'+ (150 +i) +'" alt="'+ i + '!" width="90" height="125" border="0">';   
}
```

Here is a working JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/m071yzsw/

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, you can create an element (a "tag" in HTML) using `document.createElement(tagName)`

A script to do what you want would look something like this:

```
// this is your <p class="image"></p> tag
var imageContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("image")[0];
// placeholder for upcoming images
var image;
// i = 20 is the starting image, i > 10 goes down to but doesn't include 10
for (var i = 20; i > 10; i--) {
    image = document.createElement("img");
    image.setAttribute("src", images + "/" + i + ".jpg");
    image.setAttribute("alt", i + "!");
    image.setAttribute("width", 90);
    image.setAttribute("height", 125);
    image.setAttribute("border", 0);
    imageContainer.appendChild(image);
}
```

A better alternative however, if you're going to do this a lot, is to use a templating library. These allow you to write a sort of an HTML "skeleton", and you can then fill in the blanks with javascript.

Comment: Why do people down vote without explaining why.. Drives me nuts.  I upvoted you to cancel it out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
var imgs=document.querySelectorAll("p.image img");//array of img objects
for(var i in imgs){//loop
    imgs[i].src="images/"+i+".jpg";//change image
    imgs[i].alt=i+"!";//change attribute
}
```

It is one of a ways to run through all the images.
Of course you can insert an array of objects with parameters that will be inserted

```
var data=[
    {src:"img/img1.png",alt:"alt1"},
    {src:"img/img2.png",alt:"alt2"},
    {src:"img/img3.png",alt:"alt3"},
    {src:"img/img4.png",alt:"alt4"},
    {src:"img/img5.png",alt:"alt5"},
    {src:"img/img6.png",alt:"alt6"},
    {src:"img/img7.png",alt:"alt7"},
    {src:"img/img8.png",alt:"alt8"},
    {src:"img/img9.png",alt:"alt9"},
    {src:"img/img10.png",alt:"alt10"},
];

var imgs=document.querySelectorAll("p.image img");//array of img objects
for(var i in imgs){//loop
    imgs[i].src=data[i].src;//change image
    imgs[i].alt=data[i].alt;//change attr
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this with Jquery:

```
//use for loop to loop over your images
    for(var i=20;i>10;i--){
    $('.image').append( '<img src="images/'+i+'.jpg" alt='+i+'!" width="90" height="125" border="0">' );//get the item with class "image" and appended your images
    }
```

Comment: Well, you could consider hovering over the javascript tag in the question.

Comment: I think cause you used JQuery and the question did not call out JQuery.  I upvoted you though to get you some of the points back.. I can not stand it when people downvote without leaving a comment

Comment: I downvoted because this answer doesn't explain anything, uses jQuery while OP never stated he uses it, and it looks rushed overall.

Comment: thanks @w3bMak3r! it's not downvoting that upsets me, but as you said down voting without comment drives me crazy

Comment: Yeah I can relate.. It has happened to me to for answers I thought where great.  It drives me nuts cause I like to learn and improve to so if someone wants to downvote then say why so I can improve my skills to :)  Awesome job noob

Comment: @Azeirah OP problem was simple to me he wanted a solution and he didn't state he only wanted pure JS did he? Then how can you down vote my working ans without a comment? Very unethical mate